# Why can't safari open the browser version of Jupyter notebook? (JupyterLite)

Tags: python, browser, jupyter-notebook, safari, macos-high-sierra

I have installed Visual Studio Code and Python 3.10.7 on my Mac. Now, I'd like to try Jupyter Notebook browser version. For some reason, the link https://jupyter.org/try-jupyter/retro/notebooks/?path=notebooks/Intro.ipynb won't open. I click on the link but nothing happens. I have Safari version 13.1.2 and macOS High Sierra 10.13.6 installed. I cannot upgrade my system software to a more current one. Do you know why this happens and how can I solve this issue?

Thank you in advance for your support.

Comment: I think it is your old system & browser that aren't compatible. Various reports of spotty working or not working with version 13 [here](https://github.com/pyodide/pyodide/issues/721#issuecomment-797117141). However, the current TryJupyter offering is **Experimental** & not a full Python kernel. It won't behave close to what you installed locally. For better consistency with your local stuff, you can try clicking `launch binder` [here](https://github.com/binder-examples/requirements) to get a session. Switch to the classic notebook interface from under 'Help' > 'Launch Classic Notebook`.

Comment: [Here](https://jupyter.org/try) is where you can see the note about it being **Experimental**. It's very cutting edge. The TryJupyter system was switched to the experimental WebAssembly-based JupyterLite/Pyodide stuff because it costs money to run the MyBinder.org resources. JupyterLite runs inside the client's browser, and so it isn't costing money to be active. That change takes a lot of pressure off the MyBinder system formerly being use for everything on that page. You can still use MyBinder.org to run full Python-backed kernels, and I'd recommend you use that.

Comment: Oops my bad, I talked too fast :) thanks ! (deleting the old comment, I can't edit :( )

Comment: @Wayne Yes, I'm definitely impressed something like this has been made available (keep up the good work I guess !)

Comment: For those, curious more about JupyterLite can be found [here](https://blog.jupyter.org/jupyterlite-jupyter-%EF%B8%8F-webassembly-%EF%B8%8F-python-f6e2e41ab3fa) and from [the main JupyterLite page](https://jupyterlite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). (Note that it seems the pyolite kernel branding featured in the blog post isn't be used in newer JupyterLite, I think.)

Comment: Note that the Python version at the MyBinder link I provided above is 3.8. Python 3.10 backing the notebook kernel is possible. [Here is an example](https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/vinkenoogm/SVM-hb-NL/HEAD) (version 3.10.5 currently). [Here](https://mybinder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto/languages.html#specifying-a-version-of-python) spells out how the developer of the repo that specifies configured it for version 3.10.

Answer (score 0):

I could not get JupyterLite (browser version) to work properly in Safari or Firefox. However, it does work in Chrome on MAC M2. The Try Jupyter link from the main Jupyter page leads you to the new experimental interface. This did not work for me in either Safari or Firefox. If you review the readme.md file, you will see a different URL [Try Jupyter](https://jupyter.org/try-jupyter). This loads a different interface that works only in Chrome (from my testing)